# how to send a single email to all user using ms flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I want to create a flow in which I can send a single email to all group members.

E.g: There a 4 members in a group:

- Test1 user
- Test2 user
- Test3 user
- Test4 user.

If I send the email to group then mail will like in To section Group name and in cc to all group members.

Comment: Is this a SharePoint group or M365 group or security group? Can you add more details about your requirements?

Comment: both group because i already get both groups. so can you tell me about this will help me

Comment: If it is a mail enabled security group or M365 group, you can directly add group email in "To" section of email. For SharePoint group, you have to first get all members from group, get their email addresses (semicolon separated in single variable) and then use that variable in "To" section of outlook email action in the flow.

Comment: is there any links or image where i can get the soluction

Comment: check this for SP groups: https://www.powertechtips.com/send-email-to-sharepoint-group-power-automate/. For other type of groups, you just need to pass the group email in flow action.

Comment: Ok may be it will help in to section add group name and in cc join output . so the only one mail will trigger to all users not individually email ???

Comment: in both the cases it will send single email only.

Comment: ok thanks i m trying to use this if something wrong will contact you?

Comment: Hey can u tell me how to get 365 groups? and send one emails to all users  and give permission to that group on a document.

Comment: In your above comments you said you are already getting the M365 groups. How you are fetching those? Which details of M365 are you getting, display name, ID, email?

Comment: actually i was get in code not in flows.